# Java, making constructor call using list of parameters?

Tags: java, object, arraylist, parameters, constructor

So, I'm reading data from a file and depending on the text read, the program will use a constructor of the class that matches the parameters on the line. So the parameters given by the line of the text are stored into an ArrayList:

```
List<Object> parameters = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Then I should somehow be able to create an object from those parameters, something like this:

```
constructor.newInstance(objects);
```

but I'm not quite sure how I could achieve that?

```
try {
            Class<?> objectClass = Class.forName("com.editor.object." +line.substring(4, from+4));
            Constructor[] allConstructors = objectClass.getDeclaredConstructors();
            for(Constructor constructor : allConstructors){
                Class<?>[] parameters = constructor.getParameterTypes();
                if(objects.size() == parameters.length){
                    for(int i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++){
                        if(objects.get(i).getClass().equals(parameters[i])){
                            if(i + 1 == parameters.length){
                                return constructor.newInstance(objects); //<-- This doesen't work, I have no idea how should I call the "random" constructor?
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Edit 1:**
An example:
I have the following line

new Platform(1, 1, 1, 1, 1);

-> Would create a new Platform object with parameters given. The referred class and constructor might be pretty much anything, so I can't rely on stuff like that. Of course I could just run that in code but I would like to learn more and that's why I won't do it the easiest way.

Comment: `Activator.createInstance()` might be useful.

Comment: I think that you'd want to use `parameters[i].isAssignableFrom(objects.get(i).getClass())` instead of `equals`, since you don't necessarily need the exact same class.

Comment: What doesn't work about the above?

Comment: @AndyTurner Turner Added a comment in code to point the part that I don't know how to deal with.

Comment: @nautilus_rs - call `constructor.newInstance(objects.toArray())`. You are currently effectively invoking `ctor.newInstance(new Object[] { objects })`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Constructor.newInstance` is a variadic method: its type signature is `Constructor.newInstance(Object... args)`. If you invoke it with the `ArrayList` as a single argument, that will be interpreted the same as:

```
Constructor.newInstance(new Object[] { objects })
```

because `ArrayList` is not an array type. This will fail unless that constructor happens to accept a single `List` parameter, and even then it could well fail because the elements in the list are not of the required type for that constructor.

Instead, you can invoke it as:

```
Constructor.newInstance(objects.toArray())
```

which "explodes" the list into the separate objects, from the point of view of invoking that constructor.